# how to fix an "IllegalStateException" error?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursors

I want to ask that why it isn't working so I can better help myself next time.    How to fix `IllegalStateException` error in android studio. I'm getting this error while the data is being retrieved from the database. The error I'm getting is an Illegal State Exception as described below.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>       Couldn't read row 6023, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
>       com.navdemo.ui.forms.FormDetailViewModel$10.run

The code, I'm getting this error on is:

```java
private void initScansForForm() {
        if (form == null) {
            return;
        }

        final String formId = form.getFormId();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<>();
                Cursor c = db.fetchFormScans(formId);
                int id = 0;
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    if (!c.isNull(0)){
                        id = c.getInt(0);

                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: "+id);
                    }
                    int formId = c.getInt(1);
                    String scanTime = c.getString(2);
                    String locationName = c.getString(3);
                    double latitude = c.getDouble(4);
                    double longitude = c.getDouble(5);

                    scans.add(new Scan(id, formId, scanTime, locationName, latitude, longitude));
                }
                setScans(scans);
            }
        }.start();
    }
public Cursor fetchFormScans(@NonNull String formId) {
        return fetchFormScans(Integer.parseInt(formId));
    }


public Cursor fetchFormScans(@NonNull String formId) `enter code here`{
        return fetchFormScans(Integer.parseInt(formId));
 }
```

Comment: error is IllegalStateException. My guess is c(Cursor) is Null or column does not exist.but i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I dont have more relevant infomation. I am using fabric for error info that error info is  shared in my question.Error is occuring in this line  id = c.getInt(0);

Comment: ok thank you.. Can u tell me how can I fix it....

Comment: Number of rows is not an issue as they can be windowed. Size of rows could be a problem. Is the `fetchFormScans()` including some potentially huge columns in the resulting Cursor?

Comment: ID is null..actually table is blank that's why occuring  Cursor is initialized problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that `!cursor.isAfterLast()` before doing `moveToNext`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure that you are getting a number in
    String formId = form.getFormId();
As your fetchFormScans() method is parsing string formId to integer so it can be problematic if your formId contains alphabets in it.